# C++ SQLite Stop Error If Column Results Are Null

Tags: c++, vector, sqlite

I am using the function below to query a sqlite database. It works for the most part, but if a  column returns {null} my application crashes.
How do I force it to ignore {null} columns and insert something else in their place.
I am thinking I will need to put an if statement in for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
However I am unsure of how to determine if the result is {null}

```
vector<vector<string> > CC_Database::query(string query)
{
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
vector<vector<string> > results;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query.c_str(), -1, &statement, 0) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    int cols = sqlite3_column_count(statement);
    int result = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        result = sqlite3_step(statement);

        if(result == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            vector<string> values;
            for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            {
                values.push_back((char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, col));
            }
            results.push_back(values);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}

string error = sqlite3_errmsg(database);
if(error != "not an error") cout << query << " " << error << endl;

return results;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A column value is `NULL` if [`sqlite3_column_type`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html)`(statement, col) == SQLITE_NULL`.